# Clarifying np.unique() values in image processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Stupid question. I have an image, and I am reading it in a grayscale through python using the `cv2` library like this:

```
image_gray = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

When I try to find the different color values in this image, I use  the following:

```
np.unique(image_gray.flatten())
```

This returns [58, 255]. What are these numbers representing? How do I get the equivalent RGB values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When loading the picture in OpenCV 2 with `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`, you specify that you want to load the image with grayscale values. That way, **every pixel of the image will take a value between 0 (for black) and 255 (for white)**.

Here, doing `np.unique(image_gray.flatten())` gives you all unique pixel values found in the image. From your results, you only have two colours present in the picture since the `[58, 255]` is a list of length 2.

In order to load the picture directly with RGB values instead of grayscale values, what you can do is:

```
# this will load the picture with colors
image = cv2.imread("input.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Now, if alternatively you want to have the corresponding RGB values after having loaded the picture as a grayscale image, you can do:

```
# this would only convert the grayscale image to a color one
# if the image was loaded with cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE, it will remain gray
# but the array will have RGB values instead of grayscale values
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

Now, **please note that if you want to get all unique RGB values taken by the pixels in a given picture, you need to do**:

```
np.unique(image.reshape(-1, image.shape[2]), axis=0)
```

This is because flattening the array would also flatten the RGB values. Here, we reshape the picture to flatten only the rows and columns of the array.

Comment: So it is exactly how I thought. If I were to blur out the image and then I get 5 pixel values, how would I turn those 5 values into equivalent RGB?

Comment: I can just load the image as a color, blur it out, and then use np.unique(image.reshape(-1, image,shape[2]), axis = 0), but I want the equivalent of the 5 pixel values.

Comment: So I don't know if this answers your question, but if for a pixel you have a grayscale value of 126 after having loaded the picture as grayscale, its corresponding RGB value would simply be [126, 126, 126] (with R = G = B = 126).

Comment: Yes, so that is my problem. How would I get those to be the actual RGB value corresponding to that pixel value? Is my question too naive?

Comment: Well I'm not sure I understand your question... But let's say that you start with a coloured image. Then you load it into cv2 as a grayscale image. You end up with each pixel taking a value between 0 and 255. Let's take a specific pixel that has a value of 135. Then, retrieving the R, G and B values of the coloured image for that specific pixel is hardly possible since a lot of combinations of R, G and B would end up being 135 after having been converted to grayscale intensities!

Comment: You can however say that the R, G, and B values of this pixel on the grayscale image are [135, 135, 135], which is just a way to express a grayscale intensity into RGB format.

Comment: That's why! Thanks. You answered my question through not understanding it haha get your reputation!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201861/discussion-between-tibbles-and-darkdrassher34).